# Noether's formula for real algebraic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, real-algebraic-geometry, euler-characteristics

Is there a version of Noether's formula for the Euler characteristic of a surface for Real algebraic surfaces?

Specifically, given $X$ a real algebraic compact smooth surface, what is the relationship between the Euler characteristic of $X$ as an algebraic scheme and the Euler characteristic of $X(\mathbb{R})$ as a topological subspace with the Euclidean topology$?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the Euler characteristic of $X$ as an algebraic scheme"?

Comment: @abx By that I mean the Euler characteristic with respect to the sheaf cohomology on it's structure sheaf.

Comment: But $X$ is an affine scheme, so this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @abx Why not? In the complex case we have that if $X$ is a complex nonsingular projective variety of dimension $n$ then $\chi_{top}(X(\mathbb{C}))=12 \chi(X) - K_X^2$. I am interested in an analogue of this over the real numbers. I clarified the statement now.

Comment: For an affine scheme $X$, $H^{i}(\mathscr{O}_X)=0$ for $i>0$, and $\dim H^0(\mathscr{O}_X)=\infty$.

Comment: @abx Please take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem_for_surfaces